# join with only max date entry

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table name= t1

```
ID | FileID | Status
1  |  3     | NO
3  |  5     | YES
4  |  3     | NO
```

Table name = T2

```
ID | FileID | From stage| Date       | Remark
1  |  3     | 14        | 20/03/2015 | file is submitted
2  |  3     | 14        | 21/03/2015 | file is not completed
3  |  5     | 14        | 20/03/2015 | file is submitted
```

I want T2 table details of **latest Date entry** only if file id **dont have Yes** status

using following query

```
select *
from (select distinct(t1.FileID)
      from t1
      where t1.FileID not in (select FileID from t1 where Status='YES')
     ) c1 ,t2 
where t2.FileID=c1.FileID and t2.FromStageID='14
order by c1.FileID
```

getting result

```
FIleID | ID | FileID | From stage| Date       | Remark
3      | 1  |  3     | 14        | 20/03/2015 | file is submitted
3      | 2  |  3     | 14        | 21/03/2015 | file is not completed
```

what i want

```
FIleID | ID | FileID | From stage| Date       | Remark
3      | 2  |  3     | 14        | 21/03/2015 | file is not completed
```

Comment: No data in your question corresponds to "last entry date".  Please fix the question.

Comment: I mean latest date .. in T2 table there is 20/3 and 21/3 date  entry i want only latest date entry means only 21/3 date entry .. i am getting both .

Comment: You should learn to write clear questions.  We cannot read your mind, only the question, so the text should match the sample data.

Comment: What are `c.FileID` and `r.FromStageID` in your query? I can't see such aliases. Can you post query that actually works?

Comment: sorry sir was by mistake i have edited now ..

Answer (score 2):

Traditionally a `cross apply` version for SQL-Server:

```
SELECT 
    tt.*
FROM
  T1
cross apply (
SELECT TOP 1 *
from t2
WHERE t2.fileId = t1.FileId
ORDER BY t2.date DESC
) TT
WHERE T1.status = 'YES'
```

This will produce best performance while being harder to understand and requires learning a new operator (if not yet)

EDIT: While below query produces a worse execution plan (still not completely awful) it easier to read. Will still perform nicely for tables with <100k records:

```
SELECT 
    t2.FileId, T2.FromStage, T2.Date, T2.remark
FROM
  T1 JOIN T2 ON T2.FileId = T1.FileId
WHERE T1.status = 'YES' AND 
    T2.Date = (SELECT MAX(T2.Date) FROM T2 WHERE T1.FileId = T2.FileId)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the latest of something, think `row_number()` and then fetch the first depending on the conditions.

The following uses `left join` instead of `not in` to find `fileid`s that do not have the appropriate match in `t1`.  This is safer, because `not in` behaves non-intuitively for `NULL` values.

Also, never use commas in the `from` clause.  This is a simple rule.  Always use explicit `join` syntax.

```
select t.*
from (select t2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by fileid order by date desc) as seqnum
      from t2 left join
           t1
           on t2.fileid = t1.fileid and t1.status = 'YES'
      where t1.fileid is null
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Why, You can Use `CommonTableExpression` and `ROW_NUMBER()` to achieve this result:

try this:[Fiddle Demo Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a7892/2)

```
create table t1(
ID int,
  FieldId int,
  [Status] varchar(50)
)
insert into t1 values(1,3,'NO'),(3,5,'YES'),(4,3,'NO')

create table T2(
Id int,
  FieldId int,
  From_Stage int,
 date1 date,
  Remarks varchar(50)
)
insert into T2 values(1,3,14,'03/20/2015','file is submitted'),
(2,3,14,'03/21/2015','file is not completed'),
(3,5,14,'03/21/2015','file is submitted')
```

Query:

```
;with cte as
(
select t1.FieldId,t2.ID,t2.From_Stage,t2.date1,t2.REmarks,
ROW_NUMBER() Over(PARTITION  by t2.FieldId order by t2.date1 desc) as rk
from t1,T2  t2 where t1.FieldId=t2.FieldId and t1.Status!='YES'
)

select * from cte where rk=1
```